# Selecting record count by month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to get a count of transaction by each for a year Oct 2020 to Oct 2021 . The following is the query for the over all year . Is there a way I can do this count by each month with out having to run 12 times this query?

```sql
select count(*)
from   Transaction_Details
where  date_created between TO_DATE('2020-10-01 01:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
                        and TO_DATE('2021-10-01 01:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss');
```

Comment: Why are you adding 1 hour to the date range and why does it start on the 10th of the month? What do you mean by "for each month"? Do you mean for each calendar month? Or each month starting from 10th of the month? Or something else? If you want it for each calendar month then there will be 13 months (including October 2020 through to October 2021).

Answer (score 1):

Truncate the date to the start of the calendar month and `GROUP BY` that:

```sql
select TRUNC(date_created, 'MM') As calendar_month_start,
       count(*)
from   Transaction_Details
where  date_created between DATE '2020-10-01' + INTERVAL '1' HOUR
                        and DATE '2021-10-01' + INTERVAL '1' HOUR
GROUP BY
      TRUNC(date_created, 'MM')
ORDER BY
      calendar_month_start;
```

If you want it starting at 1am on the 1st of each month then:

```sql
select TRUNC(date_created - INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 'MM')
          + INTERVAL '1' HOUR AS month_from_1am_on_1st,
       count(*)
from   Transaction_Details
where  date_created between DATE '2020-10-01' + INTERVAL '1' HOUR
                        and DATE '2021-10-01' + INTERVAL '1' HOUR
GROUP BY
      TRUNC(date_created - INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 'MM')
ORDER BY
      month_from_1am_on_1st;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4266578bfe7de1af08fe804121bf5ccb)*